# Accessing blocked websites in a country with Internet censorship; preferably with whitelisting, to allow normal connection for non-blocked websites

Tags: firefox, software-rec, browser-addons, proxy, opera

I will be staying in a country that has Internet censorship in the near future (it's one of these countries: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Internet_censorship#Substantial ) and I would like to ask for freeware software recommendations that will allow me to access blocked websites while being able to use the normal, no-proxy connection for unblocked websites (for faster access), preferably by allowing to add the blocked websites to a whitelist.

Although my preferred browser is Opera, I am also looking into solutions with Chrome or Firefox. The OS I will be using is Windows 7.

Also preferable, but not required, is if the proxy has fast access speed (ping and bandwidth).

Note: I already tried the proxy software, [Freegate](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Freegate) with the Firefox proxy management extension, [FoxyProxy](http://getfoxyproxy.org/) (has a whitelist that allows a blocked website to be accessed thru proxy while allowing the rest to use the normal, non-proxy connection) but I get this error page when trying to access a website thru proxy: http://note.dit-inc.us/swprompt.html , which basically states that the servers gives out higher priority to China and Iran-based users (understandably), making only a limited number of sites available to Non-China or Non-Iran-based users. As I will not be staying in China or Iran, Freegate will be of limited usefulness to me.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're asking for (as it isn't selective), but have you considered using a plain VPN service?

I've used [iPredator](https://www.ipredator.se) in the past when in similar situations and its bandwidth has been ample, almost indistinguishable from my ISP's connection.

However, I couldn't comment on whether using an 'obvious' VPN provider would be blocked by TPTB in your destination country.

Comment: Does iPredator have a free version? I prefer free (as in beer) software and/or proxies.